# Should I run database queries while binding in a Laravel Service Provider?

Tags: laravel, service-provider

The following is basically what I have right now and it seems to be working. But I've found people saying that you shouldn't run database queries in the Service Provider because not everything may be registered yet. Are there potential issues with doing the config this way? And if so is there an alternative way to setup a similar situation where I grab configuration data from a database?

I was originally using a config file to bind an instance of the object I wanted

**config/payment.php**

```
'test' => array(
    'terminalid' => env('TERMINAL'),
    'secret' => env('SECRET'),
),
```

**PaymentServiceProvider** in the register method

```
  public function register()
  {
      $this->app->bind(Gateway::class, function ($app) {
          $gateway = new Gateway();
          return $gateway->initialize([
              config('payment.test')
          ]);
      });
  }
```

But I want to change this to base the configuration off a database query.

**Settings table**

| license | terminal | secret |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | ABC123 | XXXX |
| demo | ZYX987 | XXXY |

So something like this

```
  public function register()
  {
      $this->app->bind(Gateway::class, function ($app) {
          $setting = Setting::where("id",request()->id)->first();
          $gateway = new Gateway();
          return $gateway->initialize([
              'terminalid' => $setting->terminal,
              'secret' => $setting->secret,
          ]);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I rather wonder why you would want to do it this way. Configurations are typically environment bound and is preferred to do within the environment variables or another type of global configuration.

Comment: We have a dynamic list of companies where everything is the same except their credentials to the gateway. I would leave everything as config arrays but we add companies often enough that database records seem more appropriate

Comment: Ah like so, I think it would be better creating a middleware for this. Assuming you're acting on a request rather than instantiation (at least in this use-case it seems so).

Comment: Yes I am using a request variable to determine what config to use. What would be the middleware equivalent? Would I add the config as a variable on the request?

Comment: A middleware is actually acting on a request. So you have all the request variables necessary without having to call to helper functions. And it would allow you to interrupt the request, in any case something goes wrong. Which would be, for loading dynamic configurations, more suitable in this use-case. Intercepting a request and acting on that would be more secure. Since you would be only calling to it when you need it, instead of it always being present in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can move code from **register** method into **boot** method

```
public function boot() {
   $this->app->bind(Gateway::class, function ($app) {
      $setting = Setting::where("id",request()->id)->first();
      $gateway = new Gateway();
      return $gateway->initialize([
         'terminalid' => $setting->terminal,
         'secret' => $setting->secret,
      ]);
   });         
}
```

So, you will be sure that all needed services are registered already

Comment: From what I understand the boot method runs after all the register methods are ran. So this should work. Are there any potential side effects of doing this method or things?

Comment: As I know there is no side effects of doing it like this. It is just not conventional. Because it is supposed that you register (bind(), singleton()) in register method, and do some initialization in boot() method.
But in your case you want some dynamic behavior, so it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

*This might be late but i think it might help a wonder soul some day.*

According to [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers#the-boot-method) and @nickc contribution it's appropriate to run code in the `boot method` of a service provider class.
however, concerning a service provider that depends on another service provider as you explained you want to read configurations from the database. In my findings it's not necessarily true that all registered providers will be available regardless of the order registration.

### The order of registration is very important.

here's my test code:

`
/*
* Application Service Providers...
*/
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

```
    App\Providers\SchoolServiceProvider::class,
```

`in my test AppServiceProvider depends on SchoolServiceProvider and SchoolServiceProvider depends on`Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,` which is at the top the providers list. this approached didn't work until i switched the order and problem solved.

`
/*
* Application Service Providers...
*/
App\Providers\SchoolServiceProvider::class,

```
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

`
I don't know why this is so but that's my finding.